Quick Parts in Word Document in a Doc Set in a sharepoint library not showing People metadata but showing all other metadata
I have an issue with Quick Parts in a word document not showing the information from metadata columns that are people columns, but showing the information from all other metadata columns.
I have a list that has about 60 columns in it, including 4 different people columns (ie contract manager, requester, etc). These columns are Site Columns.
I have a power automate flow attached to this list, where every time a new item is added it creates a Document Set within another document library (the Repository). That document set has metadata columns setup that are the Site Columns that are used in the List. The Power Automate Flow then updates each of the Doc Set columns with the information contained in the List Item.
I have set up content types linking to templates that have Quick Parts elements for particular column information.
If I set up Default Content to be created in the Doc Set when the Doc Set is created, the People columns are populated.
If I "+ Add a new item" to the Doc Set, picking one of the content types from the New menu, or if I drag and drop one of the templates into the Doc Set, the Quick Parts that reference people columns don't fill at all but every other Quick Part (that doesn't reference a people column) fills properly.
I cannot understand the issue and grateful for any and all advice received.
